# Retrieving a Hashmap from Shared Preferences

Tags: android, hashmap, sharedpreferences

I want to store and retrieve a hashmap from sharedpreferences and I am having trouble in retrieving the data.  The code snippet is below:

```
public void saveItemIds(Context context, HashMap<String,Integer> Ids) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Editor editor;
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(profileIds);
    editor.putString(KEY, jsonFavorites);
    editor.apply();
}

public HashMap<String,Integer> getIds(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    HashMap<String,Integer> Ids = new HashMap<>();
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (settings.contains(KEY)) {
        String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(KEY,null);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
```

// what do i do here?
//

```
    }
    return Ids;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your HashMap in a File and can fetch when needed.

Something like this :

```
    public void serializeMap(HashMap<String,String> hm) {
try {
    FileOutputStream fStream = openFileOutput(namefile.bin, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ;
    ObjectOutputStream oStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fStream);

    oStream.writeObject(hm);        
    oStream.flush();
    oStream.close();

    Log.v("Serialization success", "Success");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.v("IO Exception", e.getMessage());
}
  }
```

Here is an [example](http://shortcutsandroid.blogspot.in/2015/03/read-or-write-serializable-arraylist.html) to do so.. You can use HashMap in place of GetterSetter class used in this example..

Hope it helps..!

Comment: Thank you. Let me check it out